# PHP SQL: Update Value of multiple rows if checkbox is checked

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm trying to update a the status column in every row that the checkbox is checked, from 'Ikke Betalt' to 'Betalt', at the same time using the submit button. Basically it's a list of participants for an event and I want to be able to 'check' them off once they've paid.

See table:

[image]

My code

```
<form method="post">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Betalt?</td>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Navn</td>
            <td>Nummer</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Antal Gæster</td>
            <td>Dato</td>
            <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php include 'deltagere.php'; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p><button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Opdater</button></p>
</form>
```

Php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM t_launch ORDER BY launch_date ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

// Output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    
    echo '<tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="betaling[]" value="' .$row["launch_id"]. '"></td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td>' . $row["launch_id"] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td>' . $row["launch_firstname"] . ' ' . $row["launch_lastname"] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td>' . $row["launch_number"] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td>' . $row["launch_email"] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td>' . $row["launch_guests"] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td>' . $row["launch_date"] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td>' . $row["launch_status"] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

else {
echo "0 results";
}

foreach ($_POST['betaling'] as $launch_id) {
mysql_query("UPDATE `t_launch` SET `launch_status` = 'Betalt' WHERE `launch_id` = '$betaling'");
}
```

The first section of the php lists the table just fine, but after searching for hours for similar case I haven't been able to crack the second UPDATE part.

I have tested the SQL UPDATE call in my database using a static ID and confirmed that that it works, but currently the page just updates without updating anything.

---

## Solved

After talking to a friend who has some experience with php, we figured out a solution:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkednames'])) {
    $ids = join(', ', $_POST['checkednames']);
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `t_launch` SET `launch_status` = 'Betalt' WHERE `launch_id` IN ($ids)") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

We had to reformat the array to fit the requirements of the sql.

NB - We also fixed some syntax errors regarding mysql and mysqli (I had them mixed up)

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code you seem to have used the wrong variable name in the update function. You use $betaling when you should use $launch_id

Edit:

Just want to point out that mysql_query is deprecated, so you might want to look at pdo or Mysqli.

Also, you can edit all the rows in one query using “WHERE launch_id IN $launch-ids”. $launchids should be a comma separated list of ids between parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for your help - your idea to use WHERE IN really helped, and we figured it out! Full solution in the top of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the form display and its logic process.

Eg: Change the form to  `<form method="post" action="another_file.php">`.

Then cut the script that process the global `$_POST` variable to the new file. It should be:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['betaling']) && !empty($_POST['betaling']) {
  foreach ($_POST['betaling'] as $launch_id) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `t_launch` SET `launch_status` = 'Betalt' WHERE `launch_id` = '$betaling'");
  }
}
```

Then once the button is submitted, the sql query is executed.

Hope this help.

UPDATED:

Change `$betaling` to `$launch_id`, you don't have the `$betaling` var.

Comment: I gave it a go - this just returns a HTTP Error 500. 
I did try this actually, but I figured my code was just fudged.

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` Need to check the `mysql_query("UPDATE...`, and, of course, include the db config file (which defined `$conn`)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp The update script is never worked. Its syntax is: `mysqli_query($con,$query);`